# Сортировка JSON структур с помощью interface{}

Tags: json, golang

Есть код в котором надо чтоб определенные структуры `JSON(Date json:"d",Revenue json:"r", Gold  json:"g")` подсчитывались и все выводилось в формат `CSV` колонками `Date`, `Revenue`, `Gold`. Вот пример текста `JSON` из которого должны определенные структуры вытаскиваться, подсчитывaться все выводится в `CSV` и таких данных много:

> "logins":[["2011-11-06",1]],"last_login":"Sun Nov 06 16:52:45 -0800 2011","d":{"2010-11-05":{"gg":0,"r":4.99,"g":0},"2011-06-22":{"gg":0,"1":{"g":100,"r":4.99},"g":100,"r":4.99},"2011-07-16":{"gg":0,"1":{"r":9.99,"g":200},"r":9.99,"g":200},"2010-11-20":{"gg":0,"r":4.99,"g":100}},"h":[{"d":"2011-06-22","wid":"1","g":100,"r":4.99},{"d":"2011-07-16","r":9.99,"g":200,"wid":"1"}],"t":{"gg":0,"1":{"g":300,"r":14.98},"r":24.96,"g":400}}

И вот код в котором надо дописать, я начал писать ниже и вот застрял, там я так понимаю case надо использовать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"log"
_"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
"compress/zlib"
"bytes"
"encoding/json"
"io/ioutil"
"sort"
"encoding/csv"
"os"
"strconv"
"fmt"
)

var (
    data []byte
    dates []string
 )

type UserStatsData struct {
    Dates map[string]Info `json:"d"`
}


type Info struct {
    R json.Number `json:"r"`
    G int `json:"g"`
    D string `json:"-"`
}

func main() {

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "name:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:port)/database")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT data FROM user_stats ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 3`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

file, err := os.Create("result.csv")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer file.Close()

cont := 0
writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
userStatsData := UserStatsData{}
for rows.Next() {
    //userStatsData := UserStatsData{}
    err := rows.Scan(&data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData); err != nil {
        r, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicf("\nCannot read archive %v", err);
        }
        r.Close()
        data, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData); err != nil{
    panic(err)
    }

    for userStats := range userStatsData.Dates {
        dates = append(dates, userStats)
    }
    sort.Strings(dates)

    var info []Info
    for _, date := range dates {
        i := userStatsData.Dates[date]
        i.D = date
        info = append(info, i)
    }

    for _, i := range info {
        if cont == 0 {
            var record []string
            record = append(record, "Data")
            record = append(record, "Gold")
            record = append(record, "Revenue")
            writer.Write(record)
            cont++

        }
        var record []string
        record = append(record, i.D)
        record = append(record, strconv.Itoa(i.G))
        record = append(record, i.R.String())
        writer.Write(record)
        cont++

    }

    writer.Flush()
    err = writer.Error()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Декодите в мап, берёте ключи, сортируете, энкодите в CSV:

```
type Data struct {
    Dates map[string]Info `json:"d"`
}

type Info struct {
    R json.Number `json:"r"`
    G int         `json:"g"`
    D string      `json:"-"`
}

d := Data{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &d)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var dates []string
for k := range d.Dates {
    dates = append(dates, k)
}
sort.Strings(dates)

var infos []Info
for _, date := range dates {
    i := d.Dates[date]
    i.D = date
    infos = append(infos, i)
}

enc := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
for _, i := range infos {
    err = enc.Write([]string{i.D, strconv.Itoa(i.G), i.R.String()})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
enc.Flush()
err = enc.Error()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bD9CzBSu7e.

Comment: Код изменен в начале.

Comment: @SergioHunter Вы уже спрашиваете новый вопрос. И новый вопрос мне не понятен, увы.